# Imported articles with no favicon show up with broken image tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, article

I'm importing an article I wrote in our company blog that apparently has no favicon. So what happens is that the `img src` is wrong, and therefore the `img alt` is shown ("favicon").

It doesn't look so pretty:

[image: "favicon" alt]

The article is located [here](http://blogs.ort.org.il/clickit/archives/45).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, this should be resolved. Would you try it again?